# Unsubscribing events before shutdown of self hosted endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, nservicebus

I have a bunch of wpf test clients which are self hosted nservicebus endpoints. The test clients are subscribing to several events of another endpoint at startup. Before the test clients are shutting down, I want their subscriptions to be removed. The first idea I came up with, was to use `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Stop()` where I unsubscribe all events.

The problem with this solution is that when nservicebus invokes `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Stop()` some objects have already been disposed. e.g. when nservicebus tries to create an object of TransportDefinition to decide if the endpoint has support for centralized pub\sub.

I'm not sure, if the problem only occurs in a self hosted scenario. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: What version of NServiceBus are you on?

Comment: Nservicebus version 4.6.3

Comment: Can you please raise an issue in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/new, this should work

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue concerning nservicebus, or if it is just misused in this scenario. 
How is IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Stop hooked up into the termination process of a self hosted bus? For example: will IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops.Stop invoke, 
if the process of the wpf client is terminated by task manager?